# QGIS - Graduated style except 0 value

Tags: qgis, style

I would like to graduate from a column of mine with decimal numbers.
For this I want to apply the Jenks discretisation and exclude zero.
I tried this, but it didn’t work…

[image]

Do you have any idea to do that?

Comment: try enclosing the column name in `""`

Comment: I tried : `"I_EVEPOP"  >  0` and `"I_EVEPOP"  >  '0'` but doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query of:

```
I_EVEPOP > 0
```

Is a binary question. You are asking QGIS, is it bigger than 0. If so it will show a 1, if not it will show a 0.

What you want is a conditional:

```
CASE WHEN I_EVEPOP > 0 THEN I_EVEPOP END
```

Answer (score 3):

`"I_EVEPOP" > '0'` should work.

Columns, when referenced in equations, need to be put in double quotation marks, any value you want to place, grab or check for in single marks.

Comment: I tried but still don't work...

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to Rule-based styling to remove 0 value from the classification. You can use Graduated classification first to classify your data using the desired column as it is and using `Mode: Natural Breaks (Jenks)` as you can see below:

[image]

However, to remove the 0 value you need to switch to Rule-Based classification, and as you can see in the following image, the highlighted rule shows the `ColumnName >= Value`. In this example `New_ID >= 0.000`

[image]

You need to change it to `New_ID > 0.000` by removing the equal `=` sign. But in this case the polygon with the value equal zero will disappear.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I would like the discretisation to be calculated without the 0. If I do that the discretisation integrated the 0 values.